# Kotlin/Native adding c library ncurses via Cinterop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I have been trying to add ncurses to Kotlin/Native using cinterop, but this error shows up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /usr/include/stdint.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
```

I checked and I have this file installed in this path.

this is my code:

src/nativeInterop/cinterop:

```
headers = ncurses.h
headerFilter = ncurses.h

compilerOpts.linux = -I/usr/include -I/usr/include
linkerOpts.linux = -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lncurses
```

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    nativeTarget.apply {
        compilations["main"].cinterops {
            val ncurses by creating {
                when(preset) {
                    presets["linuxX64"] -> includeDirs.headerFilterOnly("/usr/include", "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu")
                }
            }
        }
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your include filter might be too strict. Try adding the parent directory of that header file to your cinterop file. On my Ubuntu install, it's in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but that's not listed in your compilerOpts.

Another note -- is there a reason to have `-I/usr/include` listed twice in your file?